# Bash mine script, please

Tags: macos, bash, unix, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

The script, in and of its self, is fairly self-explanatory.
Can this script be further improved?

First iteration was writ upon OS X 10.5.8 Leopard, current iteration was run upon OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard with Safari 5.0.2 (6533.18.5).
Also, any illumination as to why the first line ' if [ -f ] ' works, but ' if [ -f ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*.localstorage ] ' generates an error? [yes, I am a bit of a Noob]

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
# SafariClear0.0.6

if [ -f ]
then
cat /dev/null > ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*.localstorage
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*.localstorage
fi

if [ -f ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*.localstorage ]
then
echo "Oy vey!"  
fi
cd ~/Library/Safari/
cat /dev/null > WebpageIcons.db
cat /dev/null > TopSites.plist
cat /dev/null > LocationPermissions.plist
cat /dev/null > LastSession.plist
cat /dev/null > History.plist
echo "Clear"
exit
```

Comment: `-f ~/…/*.localstorage` will expand the wildcard to the file names of all `localstorage` files that exist, which `-f` can't test. You'd need to do that one at a time. I don't see the point of that statement though if all you do is `echo "Oy vey"`... So, what exactly do you want to do and where are you stuck? What doesn't work?

Comment: For those who want to migrate this to Stack Overflow: Please reconsider. The OP hasn't done any research effort and failed to write a precise question. Stack Overflow wouldn't want this question either. HomelyPoet, please [edit] your question and boil it down to the actual problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it will be closed out, not sure why, maybe because it's a programming question on Superuser.

1) the test [ -f ] doesn't make sense. The -f test is to test to see if something is a file and it exists. Having  -f with no file does nothing.

2) Seeing if "a directory contains one or more files" is harder than it seems on first glance. Luckily you don't really need to. See #3 below.

3) The first chunk of code truncates files, which you then delete. Why bother truncating at all? Just delete them and be done with it. You can do:

```
find ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/ -type f -name '*.localstorage' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

4) You then truncate some other files. This can be looped, which may be an improvement.

```
cd ~/Library/Safari/
for FILE in WebpageIcons.db TopSites.plist LocationPermissions.plist LastSession.plist  History.plist
do
    cat /dev/null > $FILE
done
```

Joining those two code snippets into a script does everything your script does.

Comment: Bash programming is usually fine. However, this just happened to be not a particularly well asked question, and I guess we don't do "code review" – that's why the votes.

Answer (score 1):

In `[ -f *.txt ]`,

- If no such file exists,

  - if the shell option `nullglob` is not enabled (the default), the word `*.txt` remains unexpanded, and `-f` evaluates to false.
  - if the shell option `nullglob` is enabled, the word `*.txt` is removed, leaving `[ -f ]`, which is equivalent to `test -f`. Since only 1 argument is given, the rule is that the expression is true if and only if the argument is not null. `-f` is not null, so the expression is true.
- If such files exist, `*.txt` is expanded to a list of their names.

  - If only one such file exists, `-f` sees the filename and evaluates to true.
  - If two such files exist, the third argument is expected to be a binary operator (`-a` or `-o`), and you probably get a `binary operator expected` error.
  - If three or more such files exist, you get a `too many arguments` error.

To test whether files matching a pattern exist, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script).